# WP Contact Form 7 : Prevent Submission of form on hitting enter key

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Contct form 7 used in wordpress site with a text area. 
By hitting the enter key it submits my form.

How can I make it to add a new line character instead of a form submit.

Also Is it possible to stop submission of contact form 7 on hitting Enter key.

I have already tried following solution but they are triggering form submission instead of Preventing contact form 7 submission.

Any help or suggestion much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

    var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7-form' );
    wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
      if (event.which == 13) { 
        console.log(" .wpcf7-form triggered ");
        event.preventDefault();
        var s=  jQuery('textarea').val();
        jQuery(this).val(s+"\n");
      }
    }, false );

    jQuery('textarea').keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.which == 13) {
          console.log(" textArea new line ");
          event.preventDefault();
          var s = $(this).val();
          jQuery(this).val(s+"\n");
      }
    });

    jQuery(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(" keydown preventDefault() ");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    jQuery(window).keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(" keypress preventDefault() ");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any of the message you've added in the console?

Comment: @Deepak thanks for your replay. Yes i am getting console for "jQuery(window).keydown" but till then contact form 7 submission is already triggered.

Comment: I see you've edited the OP. Are you now getting `console.log(" .wpcf7-form triggered ")` this message.

Comment: Nope not getting console for "console.log(" .wpcf7-form triggered ")"

Comment: Hi, I just check your code is working fine for me. where you are putting that code.?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh I'm doing this code for WordPress contact form 7. I want to stop "EnterKey Press = Submit form"

Comment: yes, I use this code for WordPress contact form 7. and it's working. now enter key stop to submit the form

Comment: In which file you are putting this code

Comment: @ShivendraSingh thanks for update. I am putting this code in footer file. BTW among this which code worked for you ?

Comment: I put your code just before the wp_footer(); in footer.php file.

Comment: you can use anyone among this - jQuery(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(" keydown preventDefault() ");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    jQuery(window).keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(" keypress preventDefault() ");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your suggestion and help. Now I am planning to switch Contact form 7 with gravity form plugin. There is built in solution in gravity form setting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've missed the class selector in this line:

```
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
```

Change it to:

```
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'submit', function( event ) {
```

Comment: Nope, did not helped your change. Contact form 7 submission triggers on enter key press.

Comment: thanks. But that new change didnot helped. Contact form 7 triggers submit event on EnterKey press